# Difference between Firefox and Chrome Installation in Ubuntu

Tags: apt, software-installation, firefox, google-chrome

I'm a new Ubuntu user and I'm learning about how to install different software. I have installed Firefox browser successfully and now I want to install Chrome browser.

`apt-cache search firefox` - I used this command to search Firefox on the internet.

`sudo apt install firefox` - I used this command to install Firefox

I have searched on the internet for information about Chrome installation and I see it is a different way to install it.

I want to know why I can't install Chrome with the same commands used to install Firefox. Also, what is the best way to install Chrome with terminal commands?

Comment: Firefox is open source, and Mozilla allows it to be packaged by the Ubuntu community. Likewise the Chromium open-source browser project can be packaged so you'll find that. Chrome however is closed-source, even though 95-98% of it is the same as Chromium,  the closed-source part means it can't be in standard Ubuntu repositories

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to install Chrome is from the official website, it will download a `.deb` file that it will install with the Software Center (but you can also download it from there and install it via terminal if you really want to).

You can't install Chrome the same way you install Firefox because it's proprietary software and isn't in the Ubuntu repositories.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome is a proprietary browser based on a fork from Chromium open-source project. You won't be able to install proprietary software the same way you install open-source software.

Firefox and chromium are both open-source.

**EDIT :**
The best way to install chrome with terminal is to follow official instructions on ubuntu documentation.

Open a terminal and type :

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list'  
wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install google-chrome-stable
```